# Deploying FLEX3 Application in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache-flex, flex3, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have a FLEX3 application - I have created a release for it and saved it in my tomcat webapps folder.
This Flex3 application consumes the Web-Services hosted on the same tomcat [axis web services]. This is how I have defined them in Flex code:

```
<mx:WebService
         id="abc"
         wsdl="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/ABC?wsdl" ></mx:WebService>
```

When I try to access the application from the browser using localhost, I am able to.
When I try to access the application from the browser on the same machine using the IPAddress, only the main page is opened and none of the web-services is called.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably put a special crossdomain.xml file to the root of the web service site because Flash denies crossdomain requests by default security configuration.

The simpliest crossdomain.xml allowing access from any location is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

When you access your application using localhost, requests are in the same domain, that's why it works.